# Why does this python script work on my local machine but not on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, gspread

there. I'm building a simple scraping tool. Here's the code that I have for it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Programming 
4 Marketers-File-goes-here.json', scope)

site = 'http://nathanbarry.com/authority/'
hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = requests.get(site, headers=hdr)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)

def getFullPrice(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', id='complete-package')
    price = ""
    for i in divs:
        price = i.a
    completePrice = (str(price).split('$',1)[1]).split('<', 1)[0]
    return completePrice


def getVideoPrice(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', id='video-package')
    price = ""
    for i in divs:
        price = i.a
    videoPrice = (str(price).split('$',1)[1]).split('<', 1)[0]
    return videoPrice

fullPrice = getFullPrice(soup)
videoPrice = getVideoPrice(soup)
date = datetime.date.today()

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("Authority Tracking").sheet1

row = len(wks.col_values(1))+1

wks.update_cell(row, 1, date)
wks.update_cell(row, 2, fullPrice)
wks.update_cell(row, 3, videoPrice)
```

This script runs on my local machine. But, when I deploy it as a part of an app to Heroku and try to run it, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 219, in put_feed
    r = self.session.put(url, data, headers=headers)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 82, in put
    return self.request('PUT', url, params=params, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 69, in request
    response.status_code, response.content))
gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (400, "400: b'Invalid query parameter value for cell_id.'")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AuthorityScraper.py", line 44, in 
    wks.update_cell(row, 1, date)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 517, in update_cell
    self.client.put_feed(uri, ElementTree.tostring(feed))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 221, in put_feed
    if ex[0] == 403:
TypeError: 'RequestError' object does not support indexing

What do you think might be causing this error? Do you have any suggestions for how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going on:

1) The Google Sheets API returned an error: "Invalid query parameter value for cell_id":

> gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (400, "400: b'Invalid query parameter value for cell_id.'")

2) A bug in `gspread` caused an exception upon receipt of the error:

> TypeError: 'RequestError' object does not support indexing

Python 3 removed `__getitem__` from `BaseException`, which this `gspread` error handling relies on. This doesn't matter too much because it would have raised an `UpdateCellError` exception anyways.

My guess is that you are passing an invalid row number to `update_cell`. It would be helpful to add some debug logging to your script to show, for example, which row it is trying to update.

It may be better to start with a worksheet with zero rows and use `append_row` instead. However there does seem to be an outstanding [issue](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/471) in `gspread` with `append_row`, and it may actually be the same issue you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. BS4 works fine at a local machine. However, for some reason, it is way too slow in the Heroku server resulting into giving error.

I switched to lxml and it is working fine now.

Install it by command:

```
pip install lxml
```

A sample code snippet is given below:

```py
from lxml import html
import requests

getpage = requests.get("https://url_here")
gethtmlcontent = html.fromstring(getpage.content)
data = gethtmlcontent.xpath('//div[@class = "class-name"]/text()') 
#this is a sample for fetching data from the dummy div
data = data[0:n] # as per your requirement

#now inject the data into django tmeplate.
```